How to Create a pie chart using gembox presentation code
I am using Gembox to create a project where i will be adding some data to a pie chart and create ppt out of it in c#. In the documentation they have not provided any sample for pie chart but they have provided for bar chart based on which I have created a code but getting some error can anyone please help me on this topci
 using GemBox.Presentation;
 using spreedsheetCharts =  GemBox.Spreadsheet.Charts;
 using spreedsheet =  GemBox.Spreadsheet;

 // Add new PowerPoint presentation slide.
 // If using the Professional version, put your GemBox.Presentation serial key below.
ComponentInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");

// If using the Professional version, put your GemBox.Spreadsheet serial key below.
SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");

    var firstLastSlidesPresentation= new PresentationDocument();

    var slide = firstLastSlidesPresentation.Slides.AddNew(SlideLayoutType.Custom);

    // Add simple PowerPoint presentation title.
    var textBox = slide.Content.AddTextBox(ShapeGeometryType.Rectangle,
        116.8, 20, 105, 10, GemBox.Presentation.LengthUnit.Millimeter);

    textBox.AddParagraph().AddRun("New presentation with chart element.");

    // Create PowerPoint chart and add it to slide.
    var chart = slide.Content.AddChart(GemBox.Presentation.ChartType.Bar,
        49.3, 40, 240, 120, GemBox.Presentation.LengthUnit.Millimeter);

    // Get underlying Excel chart.
    spreedsheetCharts.ExcelChart excelChart = (spreedsheetCharts.ExcelChart)chart.ExcelChart;
    spreedsheet.ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelChart.Worksheet;

    // Add data for Excel chart.
    worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Name";
    worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "John Doe";
    worksheet.Cells["A3"].Value = "Fred Nurk";
    worksheet.Cells["A4"].Value = "Hans Meier";
    worksheet.Cells["A5"].Value = "Ivan Horvat";

    worksheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "Salary";
    worksheet.Cells["B2"].Value = 3600;
    worksheet.Cells["B3"].Value = 2580;
    worksheet.Cells["B4"].Value = 3200;
    worksheet.Cells["B5"].Value = 4100;

    // Select data.
    excelChart.SelectData(worksheet.Cells.GetSubrange("A1:B5"), true);
    
    firstLastSlidesPresentation.save("somename.pptx")

error -
‘ExcelChart’ does not contain a definition for ‘Worksheet’ and no accessible extension method ‘Worksheet’ accepting a first argument of type ‘ExcelChart’ could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
I tried to find many places where i can get a code for this issue but there is no solution and also the gembox documentation is not clear on this the code i used is almost identical to the bar chart.

The ExcelChart.Worksheet property and the support for reading charts in PowerPoint files was added in later versions of GemBox.Spreadsheet than the one you're currently using. So, try again using the current latest version.
Regarding the pie chart, just change the GemBox.Presentation.ChartType. For instance, like this:
var chart = slide.Content.AddChart(GemBox.Presentation.ChartType.Pie,
    49.3, 40, 240, 120, GemBox.Presentation.LengthUnit.Millimeter);

